# Use UIButton instead of Segmented Control

Tags: ios, uibutton

I created an NSArray Object to toggle between different label texts. The label in my interface builder says "0." When pushing the button toggleText, the number changes to 1, and when pressing it a second time, it changes to 2, as expected.

But how can I, by default, start with the number 1? I tried to change my label to 1 in the interface builder, but then the number stays 1 when pushing the button the first time (which makes sense). I also tried to add "self.index=0;" and "self.index=1;" in the viewDidLoad section. Nothing seems to be working... any help?

Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)toggleText
{

    if (!self.numbers)
    {
        self.index = 0;
        self.numbers = @[ @"1", @"2"];
    }

    NumberLabel.text = self.numbers[self.index];
    self.index = (self.index == self.numbers.count-1)? 0 : self.index+1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `self.index` property to 1 initially, either in your `toggleText` method or in your view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
if (!self.numbers)
{
    //self.index = 0; 
    self.index = 1;
    self.numbers = @[ @"1", @"2"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your button method (label is the IBOutlet to the UILabel):

```
-(IBAction)iterateNumber:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.label.text intValue] +1];
}
```

Comment: This is a bad practice, it violates the Model-View-Controller pattern.